# `npm audit` keeps returning "Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.". How do I make it work again?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-audit

Here is the error I get:

```
npm ERR! code ENOAUDIT
npm ERR! audit Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.
```

with the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'audit' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.12.0
4 verbose npm-session 65e7a3436fc1253b
5 timing audit compress Completed in 25ms
6 info audit Submitting payload of 217372 bytes
7 http fetch POST 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits 13252ms
8 verbose stack Error: Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.
8 verbose stack     at Bluebird.all.spread.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/audit.js:172:18)
8 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
8 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
8 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
8 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
8 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
8 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
8 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
8 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
9 verbose cwd /Users/danielhasegan/workspace/code
10 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
11 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "audit"
12 verbose node v10.12.0
13 verbose npm  v6.4.1
14 error code ENOAUDIT
15 error audit Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried multiple ideas found across github but I do not have any `proxy` or `http-proxy` set. both of those return `null`:

```
npm config get proxy
npm config get https-proxy
```

Any ideas? This is not transitory, ive been getting it for a while now. I find it weird I get `503`. It means something is wrong with my connection.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://status.npmjs.org/incidents/vnmt8kf52bh4) is happening again?

Comment: Are you in the Dublin region? There is an open incident on the status page, although symptoms are different than your issue: https://status.npmjs.org

Comment: No, this is in San Francisco. I've been having it for weeks now.

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue. Anyone find a solution? I tried:
npm remove nodemon
npm install --save-dev nodemon
npm audit fix
Other have reported this fixing their issue. However this doesn't fix mine.

Comment: @llamacorn why do you think `nodemon` was the issue? Can you point to the place where people were talking about that?
I am thinking that its either a weird package or the package-lock file is too large.

Comment: @DanielHasegan I tried a few things found. This is one of the resources I was using, however it did not solve my issue. https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-fails-with-enoaudit-on-500-response/3629/5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running `npm update` and then `npm audit`. This should fix the problem.

Comment: In case it was unclear updating npm let me run npm audit fix too.

Comment: npm update is not updating npm but your dependencies

Comment: This is just dangerous, updating your dependencies could cause havoc for people

Answer (score 10):

You could have it when in your `package.json` you have something like `"PACKAGE_NAME": "github:USERNAME/PACAKGE_NAME"`, or any other different pattern rather than the typical one, i.e. `"PACKAGE_NAME": "PACKAGE_VERSION"`.

Comment: thats it dude! Thanks

Comment: Actually I think it fixed itself with a new version of NPM

Comment: I had the same problem with an invalid repository URL. The problem was solved after fixing the URL
`"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://domain/path/repo.git"
  }`

Comment: I have this issue trying to run the final version of this https://github.com/VelizarMihaylov/medium-keystone-react-cms, but there is not such patter in that, so I would assume this is really the issue

Comment: @DanielHasegan, have you unaccepted this answer after... 1+ year? :-|

Comment: i'm getting the same problem with the same reasoning when I revert from atypical to typical it does not error. I need to use the atypical as the original dependencies are no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

First

> `npm install -g npm`

then

> `npm audit`

may solve your problem

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. do you mean i should update my node to latest for this to work?

Comment: I take this solution from a github issue, and it worked for me. Maybe you should deeply search what is the problem.

Comment: first run "npm audit" then run "npm audit fix". The reason being not all could be fixed automatically, some may need manual fix.

Answer (score 2):

i have tried all the answers mentioned but no luck.
**it works for me only** when i **removed** **both** `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
after that i run `npm install` and then `npm audit fix` then it worked

Comment: I'm upvoting this because in my case, I got this same error due to a broken `package-lock.json` file, caused by a botched merge Renovate had made. The error message makes it sound like there's something wrong with the npm registry when the issue was on my end the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

For me problem was in my npm profile and none of the above mentioned fixes worked.

Doing the following fixed the issue.

1. Install npmrc if it's not already available

```
npm i npmrc -g
```

2. Create a profile for the public NPM registry

```
npmrc -c npm
```

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/

Reference : https://docs.open-registry.dev/known-issues-and-workarounds/

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer given at https://npm.community/t/your-configured-registry-https-registry-npmjs-org-does-not-support-audit-requests/3600/6 worked, where none of the above answers helped:

> delete your node_modules folder then try running npm install --> npm update --> npm audit

Comment: Hi Stephen, any other ideas? I used those steps with no luck:  delete the node_modules folder, npm install, npm update, npm audit. I get the error "socker hang up", "audit endpoint returned an error". It seems like I can do everything other than perform an audit on the latest version of npm. I'm wondering if this is somehow related to trying this in Windows Subsystem for Linux. It happens in Ubuntu and Debian. I can use wget successfully from to access websites.

Comment: Sorry, no idea - I'm definitely not an expert in this area

Answer (score 0):

For me only after removing `package-lock.json` and running `npm update` I could run `npm audit`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident this is a service issue with the NPM servers. I got this same issue, across all projects, in CI and development machines. So unlikely to be environment or `package.json` issues.

Notice the error:

> http fetch POST 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits 13252ms

A 503 is a server issue:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.
>
> Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded. This response should be used for temporary conditions and the Retry-After HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503

Simply waiting some time for whatever issue in the NPM service to be resolved fixed it for me. I suspect all these answers about updating npm, removing `package-lock.json`, deleting `node_modules` simply cause a delay for the service issues to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to fix this is remove folder **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

We have a private registry mentioned in the `.npmrc` file that was preventing the audit. I just commented that out to run the audit.

I would not recommend `npm update`, especially on enterprise applications like mine, that have hundreds of modules and tens of internal and external dependencies.