# Your configured registry does not support audit requests ~ On npm audit

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, continuous-integration, npm-audit

I have 1 dependency in a form of `"protobufjs": "git+https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire.git#master"`, i.e. installed using `npm install --save https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire#master`. Is there any way to include this in `npm audit`? Whenever I'm trying to audit the package, which I need to fetch that way my `npm audit` fails with the following error:

```
$ npm audit
npm ERR! code ENOAUDIT
npm ERR! audit Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests, or the audit endpoint is temporarily unavailable.
```

This is really annoying in terms of CI, because my pipeline fails then.

This question is unrealted with [`npm audit` keeps returning "Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.". How do I make it work again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953917/npm-audit-keeps-returning-your-configured-registry-https-registry-npmjs-or/57535957#57535957), didn't find answer there (or anywhere else).

Comment: This is working for me.  Create a clean directory, do `npm init` to create a package.json, then `npm install https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire#master`, then `npm audit` and it generates a clean report.  This is with npm 6.9.0.  Maybe something in your `.npmrc` configuration is causing this?

Comment: @broofa thanks for the fresh idea! Removing everything from `node_modules` and installing it again fixed this, and the pipeline passes as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @broofa for a quick test and a fresh idea, solution:

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm install https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire#master`
4. `npm audit` works again!

There was some problem with incompatibility or something in `node_modules`, I did also delete `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and generated a new one.